# Handling undefined error JQuery GetJson

Tags: jquery

I am using getJSON() to query an online plane image database and return a link and image url. My issue is that if the item is not in the database, I will get this error on the console:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I have used `var error = res.status` with

```
if (error == "404") {   
    $("#image").attr('src', "placeholder.jpg");
}
```

to show the default image for when there is no picture but it does not work. Here are the two examples of responses from the server:

Error:

> {"status":404,"error":"Aircraft thumbnail not found."}

Image in database:

```
{"status":200,"count":1,"data":[{"image":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/images\/aircraft\/thumbnails\/001\/369\/001369561.jpg","link":"http:\/\/www.airport-data.com\/aircraft\/photo\/001369561.html","photographer":"magnaman"}]}
```

My question is how can I get around the undefined error or display the default image if it is not in the database

Thanks in advance

```
  var imgUrl
$.get('http://192.168.1.64:8080/VirtualRadar/AirportDataThumbnails.json?icao='+value.Icao, function(res) {
    var imgUrl = res.data[0].image
    var error = res.status
    var imgHref = res.data[0].link

    if (error == "404") {
        $("#image").attr('src', "placeholder.jpg");
    } else {
        $("#image").attr('src', imgUrl);
                $("#image2").attr('src', imgUrl);
                $("#imageurl").attr('href', imgHref);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's an error, there's no `res.data` property. You should only access this in the `else` block.

```
$.get('http://192.168.1.64:8080/VirtualRadar/AirportDataThumbnails.json?icao=' + value.Icao, function(res) {
  var error = res.status;
  if (error == "404") {
    $("#image").attr('src', "placeholder.jpg");
  } else {
    var imgUrl = res.data[0].image;
    var imgHref = res.data[0].link;
    $("#image").attr('src', imgUrl);
    $("#image2").attr('src', imgUrl);
    $("#imageurl").attr('href', imgHref);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Should of figured it out.